# Kohana Prepared Statements or Query Building?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm trying to get to grips with Kohana framework for a new project. I just wanted to ask what your thoughts were on the two different methods for executing queries. Does one method pose any limitations?

http://kohanaframework.org/guide/tutorials.databases
1. Prepared Statements
2. Query Building

I want to make the right decision before I start building the app.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both have their own machnism to escape the user input. I prefer the Query Builder, because I think it is easier to read later on. But that is just a matter of taste. Both are the same and will have the same limitations.

Offtopic: Have a look at the ORM that comes with Kohana 3. It is really easy and works like a charm. I only use the query builder for complex queries.

Comment: Thanks Stegeman - been looking into Kohana's ORM. Think thats the way to go. Few links for those interested:

Comment: https://github.com/jheathco/kohana-orm/wiki and https://github.com/kohana/userguide/blob/master/guide/tutorials.orm.md

Comment: `Both are the same and will have the same limitations.` ? Prepared statements are not the same of Query Builder.. for example, prepared stmt decrease the database execution time while used into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared Statements are useful when you cant build query with a QBuilder (DB engine-specific commands, like 'UNLOCK TABLES'). For all standard queries (select/insert/update/delete) I recommend you QBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write SQL, then write it. The query builder is for people that can't write SQL. Using the ORM is a different story, thats all by preference. I love to write all my queries manually, makes it easier for me to test against the database manually.